# Baby rudin theorem 8.18

Tags: convex-analysis, gamma-function, holder-inequality

$\Gamma(x) = \int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt.$

Here is the Hölder's inequality:

(1/p) + (1/q) = 1.

|$\int_a^bfg$ $d\alpha$| $\leq$ {$\int_a^b$ $|f|^p$ $d\alpha$}$^{1/p}$ {$\int_a^b$ $|g|^q$ $d\alpha$}$^{1/q}$.
The 8.18 theorem says that log $\Gamma$ is convex on (0,$\infty$).

Here is the proof of this:

If 1 < p < $\infty$ and (1/p) + (1/q) = 1, apply  Hölder's inequality to $\Gamma(x)$ and obtain $\Gamma(\frac{x}{p} + \frac{y}{q})$ $\leq$ $\Gamma(x)^{1/p}\Gamma(y)^{1/q}.$
This is equivalent to this : "log $\Gamma$ is convex on (0,$\infty$)."

This means that $\int_0^\infty t^{\frac{x}{p} + \frac{y}{q} - 1}e^{-t}dt$ $\leq$ ${\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt}^{1/p}{\int_0^\infty t^{y-1}e^{-t}}dt^{1/q}$.
I couldn't relate this inequality to the Hölder's inequality. I don't understand how did we obtain this.
I also don't understand the idea of the convexity of log $\Gamma$. As I know the definition of convexity of function I couldn't relate this inequality: $\Gamma(\frac{x}{p} + \frac{y}{q})$ $\leq$ $\Gamma(x)^{1/p}\Gamma(y)^{1/q}$ to the idea of $log\Gamma(x)$ convexity on (0,$\infty$).
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We have $$t^{x/p + y/q-1} e^{-t} = t^{x/p + y/q -1/p -1/q} e^{-t/p-t/q} =t^{(x-1)/p} e^{-t/p} t^{(y-1)/q} e^{-t/q}.$$ Then use Hölder.

Comment: For the second write $\lambda=1/p$, then $1/q=1-1/p=1-\lambda.$$

Comment: Thank you . it's understandable